# Clear previous $_GET values or not to get values of only hidden fields

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, get

I have radio buttons which when selected populate a dropdwn menu from mysql. Below is the code for the radio button:

```
<div>
  <input type="radio"  id="radioButton1" name="design" style="vertical-align: middle"  value=3 <?php echo ($_GET['design'] == 3 ? 'checked' : '') ?>/>
  <label for="design">Single Vision</label> 
</div>
```

I have five radio buttons with different ids. Depending on which  radio button is checked javascript enables the display to block. This is part of the javascript:

```
if (form.radioButton1.checked) {
  sv2.style.display = "none";
  sv3.style.display = "none";
  sv4.style.display = "none";
  sv5.style.display = "none";
  sv.style.display = "block";
  sv.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I have five dropdown menu all with display:none.

Now depending on the checked radio button this is the code for the dropdown menu to be shown:

```
<select style="width:200px; display:none" name="pGroup1" id="sv" >
  <option value="Choose an Option" selected="selected">Choose Single Vision Product Group</option>
  <?php $selGroup = isset($_GET['pGroup1'])?$_GET['pGroup1']:"";
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT pGroup FROM cr39 WHERE ";
    $sql.="HeadingNo = 3  ORDER BY pGroup ASC";
    $result =mysql_query($sql);
    while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  ?>
  <option <?php if($data['pGroup'] == $selGroup) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>  value ="<?php echo $data['pGroup'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['pGroup'] ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

I am using the GET method and the submitted form has values of dropdown menu  display:none. This creates a problem on my query as I need only the value of the select with display:block not other select with display:none.

Comment: Another option would be not to have multiple SELECTs, but to have a SELECT whose OPTIONs are filled via an AJAX-method, depending on the selected RADIO-button.

Comment: @FirmView I want the values to be shown on my url. Will POST method not send hidden fields?

Comment: "values to be shown on my url" - is that a requirement?

Comment: POST method can send hidden fields

Comment: POST method is always better than GET

Comment: @feeela How do you use an AJAX-method to fill the drop down menu?

Comment: @FirmView Its not a requirement to have values on my URL. However the hidden fields especially prevous sent ones show up in my query.

Comment: If you use POST method none of the values will be shown in URL

Comment: @Sithelo http://catcode.com/formguide/getpost.html go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your submitting a form with radio buttons and the value of the form modify a query which displays a select box.  If that is so, why not use $_POST instead of $_GET?  Also, be sure to escape and sanitize your data with `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pGroup1'])` or `htmlspecialchars($_GET['pGroup1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

AJAX Solution:

Use the following HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup-single" value="1" /><label for="radioGroup-single">Single Vision</label> 
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup-whatever" value="2" /><label for="radioGroup-whatever">Whatever Vision</label> 
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup-another" value="3" /><label for="radioGroup-another">Another Vision</label>
```

Use the following jQuery:

```
$("input:radio[name=radioGroup]").click(function() {
    var pGroupId = $(this).val();
    $('#myDropdownDiv').load('myDropdownBoxPage.php?pGroupId='+pGroupId);
});
```

Put a DIV in your page like this that will be filled with the contents:

```
<div id="myDropdownDiv"></div>
```

Create a page like this called `myDropdownBoxPage.php`:

```
<select style="width:200px; display:none" name="pGroup1" id="sv" >
  <option value="Choose an Option" selected="selected">Choose Single Vision Product Group</option>
  <?php $selGroup = isset($_GET['pGroupId'])?$_GET['pGroupId']:"";
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT pGroup FROM cr39 WHERE ";
    $sql.="HeadingNo = 3  ORDER BY pGroup ASC";
    $result =mysql_query($sql);
    while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  ?>
  <option <?php if($data['pGroup'] == $selGroup) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>  value ="<?php echo $data['pGroup'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['pGroup'] ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The problem is hidden show up with values in my query. Previous values are not cleared as well.

Comment: Can you remove the hidden fields from the form, then?  Only include the data you want to submit inside the form (i.e. the radio buttons).

Comment: My apology. The fields are not hidden but have display:none. The dropdown menu display changes to none to block depending which radio button is selected.

Comment: This approach is not ideal being as it sends many requests to the server.  It is recommended, instead, to use AJAX to simply generate a page with a query string.  The results of the page are shown on your page.  Please let me know if you need help with this solution.

Comment: I do need solution with this. I am not quite familiar AJAX.

Comment: Please review my edits and post a new question if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm confused, but it sounds like you're telling us the form is submitting the values for all radio buttons?

Make sure that all radio buttons have the **same value for the name attribute**.

Comment: The form is not submitting all the values of the radio buttons. Its the dropdown menu that has all its value submitted. Please noe that I want to submit values or GET values of the dropdown with display: block.